# Coinbase transaction smaller than .001 btc? & Blockchain says my Bitcoincore wallet is invalid

Tags: transaction-weight

I'm trying to figure out how to send tiny transactions, like 10 cents.  Coinbase says the minimum is .001btc.  That seems rather large.  Is that just a coinbase requirement?

Also, my blockchain wallet says that my bitcoincore wallet receiving qr code is an "Invalid Bitcoin address: "  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's just a Coinbase limitation. Technically, you can send transactions however large or small you like. However, it's probably not worth the while to send a 10 cent transaction, and your recipient will probably have a hard time trying to spend such a small 'dust' transaction, because the fees required to send the transaction (and spend it) will be much higher than the 10 cents the transaction is worth. If you are regularly trying to send such small transactions, it is recommended to look into solutions such as Lightning Network that make it feasible.

Comment: Good point re. using Lightning.

Answer (score 1):

> **Also, my blockchain wallet says that my bitcoincore wallet receiving qr code is an "Invalid Bitcoin address: " Why?**

It might be that your Blockchain.com wallet doesn't yet [support](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32_adoption) the [Bech32](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32) address format (addresses starting `bc1...`) introduced *four years ago*.

Comment: It's hard for me to learn much about blockchain.com.  Info and support doesn't come easy.  Am considering leaving and using a hardware wallet like Bitbox2.  Any suggestions?